# How can I get my fitted curve to go through a specific point in Python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm having a problem trying to fit a function to my data. I want the fitted curve to go exactly through point (0,0). But it doesn't even go down to 0. Can anyone tell me what I can do? Thank you in advance!

Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x, D):
    return 1-(8/((np.pi)**2))*(np.exp(D*x*((np.pi)**2)/64))


xData = np.array([0, 3, 7, 10, 17, 21, 27, 31, 34, 42, 49, 52, 56, 64])
yData = np.array([0, 0.316045, 0.358446, 0.452339, 0.581898, 0.651380, 0.829214, 0.789857, 0.783002, 0.785944, 0.879307, 0.901747, 0.911792, 0.938174])

sigma = np.ones(len(xData))
sigma[[0, -1]] = 0.01

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, p0=(1), sigma=sigma)
print(popt)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(xData, yData)
xdata = np.arange(0.0, 65.0, 0.01)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt))
text = "$f(x)=1-(8/pi^2)exp{D(pi^2)*x/l^2}$ | D=%.9f" % tuple(popt)
plt.annotate(text, xy=(0.05, 1.05), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=12)
plt.xlim([-2, 65])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

My curve so far (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXcrO.png)

Comment: Use a model function that goes through (0, 0). Yours goes through (0, 1-8/pi^2).

Comment: Since you are including 0,0 in your data, assigning a low weight (in Sigma) to the origin point will allow your function curve to touch it in the plot. See if you can give a very low Sigma weight to (0,0).